# How to heat frozen stuffed pretzels other than bake them

Tags: pretzels

I have sold the super pretzels for years and heat them by microwave. However I am now selling their "cousin" which is made by the same company but they are stuffed with sweet cream cheese, jalapenos and mozerella cheese, and pizza sauce and cheese. I find the outside to be okay visually but the inside stuffing does not turn out as nice when done the same way. It is more rubbery. What/how can you heat these so they turn out like they have been in an oven but can be done quickly. I am in a concession trailer so space, power and time are all critical.

Comment: Ask the company that makes them.

Comment: What, in particular, is wrong with the fillings when you microwave them? And you say "other than baking them", but I guess you mean "other than microwaving them and without a full-size oven"?

Comment: @Ecnerwal is spot-on. I also ran concessions for years and sold Super Pretzels. We had one of these: http://www.wotol.com/images/thumbs/800x800/374855_1cbda343f88d77b8505e2294b60c8af1.jpg I'm sure Super Pretzel will have a similar warmer for their stuffed pretzels. They have a *Contact Us* form on their website, [superpretzel.com](http://superpretzel.com/).

Comment: I asked SuperPretzel and all they could tell me is that I would need to put them in an oven for 5-10 minutes if I did not do the microwave. 
There is not time to do this in my concession trailer with the way I have my system set up. I need to be able to deliver this completely cooked/heated in less than 2 minutes. They suggested using a warming cabinet but when I am cranking these things out what one of them will hold is not near enough. Make too many and you will be throwing out a lot. What about a convection/microwave combo?

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not have specific instructions from the company making them or a special warmer (see comments), I would try microwaving them first (e.g. defrost) and then broiling/baking them.

Alternatively, I've seen fast food cooks blast frozen foods in the microwave at high for a little while before throwing them into the deep-fryer, maybe that could be an option as well.

Or, since you mentioned that space/power/time is of the essence, you might even be able to use a combined microwaving/broiling function in case your oven offers it.

Experiment a little and you should be able to get the settings right quite fast.

PS: I'm assuming that thawing a few products beforehand is undesired and therefore leaving out that possible option.